# Error in group_vars: argument "x" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Trying to create a donut chart using plotly on shiny. I just kee getting an error:
"Error in group_vars: argument "x" is missing, with no default"

Don't know what's wrong ?
I want to manipulate the donut chart using the slider. I can see the slider, but cannot see the donut chart.

data - this pattern will repeat until 2017. I want to find a total value of measures: Americans and Asians via donut chart and manipulate it with the year slider.

```
STATE    YEAR    measure    value

CA       2005    AMERICAN   50000
NY       2005    AMERICAN   50000

CA       2005    ASIAN      50000
NY       2005    ASIAN      50000
```

reproduced data

```
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("ENROLL", 
"GRADES_ALL_AM", "GRADES_ALL_AS", "GRADES_ALL_BL", "GRADES_ALL_HI", 
"GRADES_ALL_WH"), class = "factor"), value = c(727716L, 121156L, 
676297L, 311432L, 5129788L, 539538L, 471918L, 104355L, 80937L, 
1980569L, 893557L, 177448L, 231632L, 1856841L, 958052L, 493957L, 
451469L, 489281L, 795719L, 211511L, 751850L, 862495L, 1600650L, 
781566L, 329408L, 834636L, 158875L, 281354L, 222846L, 177722L, 
653488L, 281407L, 2663637L, 1112636L, 118793L, 1834239L, 312817L, 
509814L, 1719829L, 138939L, 631613L, 107050L, 844668L, 3535333L, 
462323L, 97454L, 1032842L, 896197L, 317719L, 829085L, 100313L, 
730004L, 123868L, 708482L, 312695L, 4120498L, 549570L, 479522L, 
103782L, 80678L, 2039884L, 1235304L, 181212L, 236774L, 1875956L, 
963071L0L, 0L, 0L, 66L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 13272L, 31832L, 515L, 26L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 58L, 
503L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8171L))
```

global.r

```
require(plotly)
require(dplyr)

dataframe_read <- read.csv("newT1.csv")

dataframe_read1 <- dataframe_read[, (names(dataframe_read) %in% c("STATE", "YEAR", "measure", "value"))]
```

server.r

```
require(shiny)
require(shinydashboard)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
   yearinput <- reactive({
    dataframe_read1%>%
      filter(YEAR == input$years)})


output$plot = renderPlotly(
r <- dataframe_read1 %>%
  group_by(measure) %>%
  summarize(count = n()) %>%
  plot_ly(labels = ~measure, values = ~count()) %>%
  add_pie(hole = 0.6) %>%
  layout(title = "Donut charts using Plotly",  showlegend = F,
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))

)
})
```

ui.r

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

shinyUI(dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Working on it"),
      dashboardSidebar(
    sliderInput(
      "years",
      "Select Year:",
      min = min(dataframe_read1$YEAR),
      max = max(dataframe_read1$YEAR),
      value =  max(dataframe_read1$YEAR),
      step = 1
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(# Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    fluidRow(
      box(plotlyOutput("plot"), width = 15, height = 400)
    )
  )   
  )
)
```

Comment: can you add the data? you can use the `dput` function to do this

Comment: can you please advice where can I add dput in my code ?

Comment: `dput(df)`. Copy the output on top of your code

Comment: tried doing that in global, ui and server as dput(dataframe_read1) , still the same error

Comment: you shall use that function to make your example reproduceable. I can not find out what is wrong without working the data. `dput` is a function to make dataframes easily available for others without sending around csv file

Comment: I have uploaded a part of reproducible data. Couldn't fit entire reproduced data.

Comment: great, will be able to have a look at it in ~1h

Comment: data does not work, it has to start with `structure(`

Comment: 'data.frame': 8171 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ STATE  : Factor w/ 80 levels "ALABAMA","ALASKA",..: 1 2 4 5 12 13 15 17 20 28 ...
 $ YEAR   : int  1993 1993 1993 1993 1993 1993 1993 1993 1993 1993 ...
 $ measure: Factor w/ 6 levels "ENROLL","GRADES_ALL_AM",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ value  : int  727716 121156 676297 311432 5129788 539538 471918 104355 80937 1980569 ...